# CSS Autoprefixer Problems

Tags: css, autoprefixer

I am probably missing something obvious, but I can't get autoprefixer to do anything in Visual Studio after installation. I load the CSS file into VS and press F1 and then select autoprefixer css. Nothing is added to the CSS file. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: you should configure autoprefixer as part of your building pipeline, it is not supposed to edit source files.

Comment: Can you explain how to run autoprefixer as part of the pipeline? Thanks